# Select elements by class based on attr then add or remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, menu, getelementsbyclassname

For one of my projects I want to store the `data` information of each element of my navigation menu when I click on a button.

I've built a one-page website with two levels of navigation.

- One main menu
- Button on the bottom of each "page"

My problem is that I've written a script to add/remove the class "selected" when I use the main menu. So everything is working fine so far BUT I want the menu to add/remove the class "selected" when I use the second level of navigation too.
That's where I'm stuck at the moment.

Here's what I have:

**My main menu:**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="btn selected" href="#accueil" data-scrollOptions="accueil">accueil</a></li>
    <li><a class="btn" href="#apropos" data-scrollOptions="apropos">à propos</a></li>
    <li><a class="btn" href="#nosprojets" data-scrollOptions="nosprojets">nos projets</a></li>
    <li><a class="btn" href="#contact" data-scrollOptions="contact">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**The button in the "page":**

```
<span class="scrolldown"><a href="#apropos" data-scroll="apropos">ScrollDown</a></span>
<span class="scrolldown"><a href="#nosprojets" data-scroll="nosprojets">ScrollDown</a></span>
<span class="scrolldown"><a href="#contact" data-scroll="contact">ScrollDown</a></span>
```

**My 1st script:** (working)

```
// onClick - class distribution
$(".btn").click(function () {
  $(".btn").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");        
});
```

**My 2nd script:** (not working)

```
// onClick - dataTrigger
$(".scrolldown").click(function() {
  $('.btn').each(function () {
    var myArray =[];
    var attributs = $('.btn').data('scroll-options');
    myArray.push(attributs);
    console.log(myArray);
  });
});
```

How can I push each value (`accueil`, `apropos`, `nosprojets`, `contact`) in my array and then use it to add/remove class?

The result for now [console.log of my array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my1NC.png)

Comment: You're using $.data('scroll-options') but your data attribute in your html is data-scrollOptions. This might be convention actually... not sure.

Comment: oups yeah, I've change some things before posting my question. It was "data-scroll-options" in my html too :)

Comment: Please select your favorite answer if your problem was resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.btn').each(function () {
    var myArray =[];
    var attributs = $('.btn').data('scroll-options');
    myArray.push(attributs);
    console.log(myArray);
  });
```

You might want to be using the 'this' context to resolve your problem. While you are in your 'each' loop, this line :

```
var attributs = $('.btn').data('data-scrollOptions');
```

won't select a single item. In fact, in this case, it is probably returning the data value for the first  $('.btn') item.

To access each value, you could do something like this :

```
var attribut = $(this).data('data-scrollOptions');
```

'this' refers to the current context. In our case, it is the scope of a single 'btn' item, in the each loop. Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome! Also, you might be interested by the jQuery's [toggleClass function](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: Oh and also, you probably want to declare you array outside of your 'each' loop. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're overcomplicating the way to do this. There's a bunch of different ways to do it, and a number of different events you could use (so don't anyone shoot me for not doing it "their preferred way"). But you could do this instead.

```
$('.scrolldown').on('click', function(){

   $('.btn', 'nav').removeClass('selected');
   $('.btn[href="'+$('a',this).attr('href')+'"]','nav').addClass('selected'); 

});
```

```js
(function($) {

  $('.scrolldown').on('click', function() {
    $('.btn', 'nav').removeClass('selected');
    $('.btn[href="' + $('a', this).attr('href') + '"]', 'nav').addClass('selected');



  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="btn selected" href="#accueil" data-scrollOptions="accueil">accueil</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="btn" href="#apropos" data-scrollOptions="apropos">à propos</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="btn" href="#nosprojets" data-scrollOptions="nosprojets">nos projets</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="btn" href="#contact" data-scrollOptions="contact">contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div>
  <span class="scrolldown"><a href="#apropos" data-scroll="apropos">ScrollDown</a></span>
  <span class="scrolldown"><a href="#nosprojets" data-scroll="nosprojets">ScrollDown</a></span>
  <span class="scrolldown"><a href="#contact" data-scroll="contact">ScrollDown</a></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's totally me, I always complicate things... xD
Thanks for your help =)